# Download AssetBundle in hard disk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now, it seems `UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle`download asset to RAM and load. Is there anyway to download to hard disk to load?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not really complicated. Handle it like a normal file you would download from the internet but save it with the *".unity3d"* extension.

**1**.Download the `AssetBundle` as a normal file by making a request with `UnityWebRequest`.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
yield return www.Send();
```

**2**.Retrieve the byte array data with `DownloadHandler.data` then save it to `Application.persistentDataPath/yourfolder/filename.unity3d`. Make sure that the extension is *".unity3d"*.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(handle.data, data);
```

That's it.

**3**.To load the data, use `AssetBundle.LoadFromFile` or `AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync`:

```
AssetBundleCreateRequest bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);
```

---

If still confused, here is what the thing should look like. You may need to make some modification:

**Download and Save:**

```
IEnumerator downloadAsset()
{
    string url = "http://url.net/YourAsset.unity3d";

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    DownloadHandler handle = www.downloadHandler;

    //Send Request and wait
    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error while Downloading Data: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success");

        //handle.data

        //Construct path to save it
        string dataFileName = "WaterVehicles";
        string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "AssetData");
        tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, dataFileName + ".unity3d");

        //Save
        save(handle.data, tempPath);
    }
}

void save(byte[] data, string path)
{
    //Create the Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }

    try
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
        Debug.Log("Saved Data to: " + path.Replace("/", "\\"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Failed To Save Data to: " + path.Replace("/", "\\"));
        Debug.LogWarning("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

**Load**:

```
IEnumerable LoadObject(string path)
{
    AssetBundleCreateRequest bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);
    yield return bundle;

    AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle = bundle.assetBundle;
    if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
        yield break;
    }

    AssetBundleRequest request = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("boat");
    yield return request;

    GameObject obj = request.asset as GameObject;
    obj.transform.position = new Vector3(0.08f, -2.345f, 297.54f);
    obj.transform.Rotate(350.41f, 400f, 20f);
    obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.0518f, 0.998f, 1.1793f);

    Instantiate(obj);

    myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I am going to run on mobile, where do you recommend to store? persistentDataPath? Also will it be problematic if I want to replace older version of my assetbundle, for example, i had assetbundle1_01, then I detect update and download assetbundle1_02, if users don't give me write permission, then that will be problematic?

Comment: Yes, use persistentDataPath. Note that you **must** create a folder inside this and store in that folder. Don't save directly to the persistentDataPath path. It should be `Application.persistentDataPath/yourfolder/filename.ext`. You can always replace the file with a new version.Finally there is a `try` and `catch` code in the save function. If there is an exception, you can check it in the catch`  block and ask the user to enable write permission. You can't write to someone's device if they don't want you to.

Comment: If you have problems on Android, make sure to change "Write Permission" to "External (SDCard)"

Comment: Thanks, I will, I wonder any chance you know how to load from streamingAssets in Android? I tried "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + myassetbundle name, with LoadFromCacheOrDownload, I cannot find the file anyhow. Does it relate to signed apk? should i use dataPath + signedKey + "!/assets/" instead?

Comment: I think you should post this as a new question with the title of *"loading assets from the streamingAssets"*. You have to post your the code you are using and also mention what's not working and I will take a look at that. And 
 also better to mention your Unity version and that's really important.

Comment: Thanks, it seems on Android, only LoadFromCacheOrDownload works. new www(),assetbundle.loadfile() and unityWebRequest does not work.

Comment: You mean for `streamingAssets` or `Application.persistentDataPath` I asked you to use in my answer?

Comment: In my app, I put assetbundle in streamingAssets, and it can only be loaded through LoadFromCacheOrDownload, I want to share this information with you.

Comment: Ok. Note that when using the StreamingAssets folder, `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload`, or `UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle` + `DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent`  should be used. If that's not the case then file for a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle + DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent does not work

Comment: @Programmer I used this method to download and save bundles but when I build my app for android it stop's working on the phone and when I call the load function it gives me the ObjectRefrence not set to an instance of an object. Btw I added the read write external permission to my android manifest. what could be wrong ?