# Saving Unity AssetBundle From WebServer to Local Storage using AssetBundle Manager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, store, assetbundle

I'm very new to unity and I got stuck in storing Asset and also I'm not a native English man so sorry for my English also.

I'm using asset bundle manager of unity and I can load assets from the server when I need them but I don't want to load the assets every time, I wanted to store the asset bundle or the asset in my project so that I can use it later.

currently, I'm using this code for loading a scene from my AssetBundle Server.

```
using UnityEngine;   
using System.Collections;   
using AssetBundles;   
using System;    

public string sceneAssetBundle;
public string sceneName;


IEnumerator Start()

{

    yield return StartCoroutine(Initialize());

}

IEnumerator Initialize()    

{    

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);     
        AssetBundleManager.SetSourceAssetBundleURL("URL");    
        AssetBundleManager.SetDevelopmentAssetBundleServer();     
        var request = AssetBundleManager.Initialize();     
        if (request != null)    
            yield return StartCoroutine(request);    

        AssetBundleLoadOperation request = AssetBundleManager.LoadLevelAsync(sceneAssetBundle, sceneName, true);    
        if (request == null)    
            yield break;    
        yield return StartCoroutine(request);    
}
```

by this I can load the scene, Also it works on my device also. But how can I store the bundle for future use?

P.S. I've also seen this [Answer]  [Download AssetBundle in hard disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226800/download-assetbundle-in-hard-disk)
But I'm not using "UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle". I'm using AssetBundle Manager as per unity AssetBundle tutorial.