# DLC System in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an app that will include DLC system. I've tried normal assetBundles but for that, I have to have an internet connection. I want to use DLC because I need to download that content once and continue using without the internet but I couldn't even find documentation for it! Thank you for your help.

I've tried assetBundles.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226800/download-assetbundle-in-hard-disk) Should Help You. This Explains all the things that you need

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to load a scene not .unity3d

Answer (score 0):

Asset bundles was created for DLC purposes. And it contains caching system from box, you can see here examples how to use it https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make a DLC package that can be downloaded only once with the relatively new Adressable Assets system https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.4/manual/index.html.

Lets say you have a map, and you make an addressable asset out of it. Basicly you would have a catalog file that would point to a version of your map (adressable), and when you would want to make a DLC you could just make a new version of that scene and package it as a new version of the adressable and the next time the players app checks if anything new is available it could see the new map and download it. You also have custom controll over which group of people could get the update and so on.