# How can I convert UnityEngine.Object[] that contains Texture2D to Texture2D[]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

How can I convert UnityEngine.Object[] to Texture2D[] ?

I am using this script :

```
    void Start()
{
    string dataFileName = "skins";
    string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "AssetData");
    tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, dataFileName + ".unity3d");

    StartCoroutine(LoadObject(tempPath).GetEnumerator());
    
}
IEnumerable LoadObject(string path)
{
    Debug.Log("Loading...");
    AssetBundleCreateRequest bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(path);
    yield return bundle;

    AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle = bundle.assetBundle;
    if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
        yield break;
    }

    AssetBundleRequest request = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync();
    yield return request;
    
    Texture2D[] obj = request.allAssets as Texture2D[]; 

    var path2 = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Item Images/";
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path2)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path2));
    }
    foreach (Texture2D s in obj)
    {
        byte[] itemBGBytes = s.EncodeToPNG();
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Item Images/" + s.name + ".png", itemBGBytes);
    }


    myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
}
```

Conversion of Object[] to Texture2D[] is not working. I got this script from the stackoverflow post ->  [Download AssetBundle in hard disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226800/download-assetbundle-in-hard-disk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If request.allAssets returns object[] which you know are Texture2D , then you can try:

```
object[] aObj = request.allAssets;
Texture2D[] aT2D = Array.ConvertAll(aObj, x => (Texture2D) x);
```

Comment: request.allAssets returns object[] and request.asset returns Texture2D. Unfortunately your code didn't work for me.

Comment: InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Edit: Your code worked when I chanced this line : 

AssetBundleRequest request = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync();

to 

AssetBundleRequest request = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync<Texture2D>();